# Get maximum number of end words in a path for all paths in a Trie

Tags: python, trie

Consider the following words:

```
'a', 'ab', 'abcd', 'b', 'bcd'
```

Adding them to a Trie will result in the following representation with the stars meaning that a node is an endword:

```
              root 
              / \
            *a  *b
            /     \
          *b       c
          /         \
         c          *d
        /
      *d
```

In this example we have two paths and the maximum number of end words in any path is 3(a, ab, abcd). How would you perform the DFS to get the max?

Here is my code for a Trie:

```py
class TrieNode:

    def __init__(self):
        self.children = dict()
        self.end_word = 0

class Trie:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = TrieNode()

    def insert(self, key):
        current = self.root
        for char in key:
            if char not in current.children:
                current.children[char] = TrieNode()
            current = current.children[char]
        current.end_word += 1
```

Comment: I don't see the need for two separate classes `Trie, TrieNode`, can't we just have on unified one? (call `insert` on the root node, and propagate it down the trie, chopping one letter at a time). `Trie.__init__()` needs to take an extra parameter and default to None.

Comment: The max should always be the root node with the problem as you described it, or eventually in one of its children if you forbid the root to be solution. What are the rules of the problem regarding this matter ?

Comment: I was trying to solve Leetcode 1048 using Tries. My approach was to sort each string in the list, put it into the trie and then return the path with largest number of words. It was the wrong approach.

Comment: It helps to give the link: [Leetcode 1048: "Longest String Chain"](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-string-chain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a method in your `TrieNode`, if I understood well your question, you want this trie :

```
          root 
          / \
        *a  *b
        /     \
      *b       c
      / \       \
     c  *d      *d
    /   /
  *d   *e
```

To return 4 (a, ab, abd, abde)

You can do it recursively:

```
class TrieNode:

    def __init__(self):
        self.children = dict()
        self.end_word = 0

    def count_end_words(self):
        if self.children:
            return self.end_word + max(child.count_end_words() for child in self.children.values())
        return self.end_word

class Trie:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = TrieNode()

    def insert(self, key):
        current = self.root
        for char in key:
            if char not in current.children:
                current.children[char] = TrieNode()
            current = current.children[char]
        current.end_word += 1

    def max_path_count_end_words(self):
        return self.root.count_end_words()

root = Trie()
for word in ('a', 'ab', 'abcd', 'b', 'bcd', 'abd', 'abde'):
     root.insert(word)

print(root.max_path_count_end_words()) # returns 4
```

As mentionned in the comment, you can avoid creating a class `TrieNode`, this is a way to do it:

```
class Trie:

    def __init__(self):
        self.children = dict()
        self.is_end_word = False

    def insert(self, key):
        current = self
        if not key:
            return
        if len(key) == 1:
            self.is_end_word = True
        char  = key[0]
        if char not in current.children:
            self.children[char] = Trie()
        return self.children[char].insert(key[1:])

    def max_path_count_end_words(self):
        if self.children:
            return self.is_end_word + max(child.max_path_count_end_words() for child in self.children.values())
        return self.is_end_word

root = Trie()
for word in ('a', 'ab', 'abcd', 'b', 'bcd', 'abd', 'abde'):
     root.insert(word)

print(root.max_path_count_end_words()) # returns 4
```

Comment: I don't see the need for two separate classes `Trie, TrieNode`, can't we just have on unified one? (call `insert` on the root node, and propagate it down the trie, chopping one letter at a time). `Trie.__init__()` needs to take an extra parameter and default to None.

Comment: @smci I totally agree, on the implementation I've done for CPT, I had one class (and a typedef for the node as it was c++). But this was te original implementation, I did not want to change it. But you are right !

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method on the `TrieNode` class that returns whether it's an end_word plus the sum of the calling the same method on all the children:

```
class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = dict()
        self.end_word = 0
    def word_count(self):
        return self.end_word + sum([word_count() for c in self.children.values() ])
```

To use it:

```
t = Trie()
for w in ('a', 'ab', 'abcd', 'b', 'bcd'):
    t.insert(w)

t.root.word_count()
# 5
```

To find the max, just call it on all the roots children and compare:

```
max(branch.words() for branch in t.root.children.values())
# 3
```

Comment: Surely `max(...)`, not `sum([word_count() for c in self.children.values()` ?

Comment: @smci, I suppose if want a method that only finds the max. I wrote a method that gets the count of children because it seems more generally useful. If you want the max, you can get it (as I do in the last line). The selected answer has a method called `count_end_words` that doesn't actually return the count of end words because it uses `max`.